# POST запрос на сервер android JAVA

Tags: java, android

на сервер (в JSON файл) нужно передать значения переменных. Как это реализовать в android ?

Да, нужно открыть файл и в него перезаписать вот эти строки (skype, mobile) {

```
    "data": "dbfriends",
    "hello": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Andrew",
            "contacts": {
                "mobile": "74.0059731",
                "email": "74.0059731",
                "skype": "74.0059731"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "40.7143528",
            "city": "Kiev",
            "contacts": {
                "mobile": "37.61787415",
                "email": "74.0059731",
                "skype": "55.77580064"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: а что у вас есть, чтобы отправить запрос? где ваш код? "на сервер (в JSON файл)" вам надо открыть файл и что-то в него дописать? или вам надо передать значения серверу и пусть сам разбирается?

Comment: Кхм... Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: тогда запросите у сервера этот файл, измените его и верните. Но если у вас там будет много данных в файле, потратите много трафика пользователю. Лучше создайте на сервере метод, который будет принимать ваши строки и сам запишет их.

Comment: Дак вот, соль то в чём, я не знаю как это сделать. Через что? Какие библиотеки использовать и прочее

Comment: попробуйте OkHttpClient часто видел его в вопросах про андроид.

Comment: Хм... Спасибо, попробую